# How to make a decent R function for rainbow table?

Tags: python

I'm trying to develop a rainbow table. The search function works well, but the problem is when I try to generate the table.

There are 54 possible characters and the passwords are 3 characters long (for now). I can generate a table with 1024 lines, and 153 columns. In theory, if there were no collisions, there would be a >95% chance that I crack the password (1024*153 ≈ 54^3).

But I'm getting 126662 collisions.... Here's my R function

```
def reduct(length, hashData, k):

  ### Initializing variables and mapping ###

  while len(pwd) != length:
    pwdChar = (int(hashData[0], 16) + int(hashData[1], 16) + int(hashData[2], 16) + int(hashData[3], 16) - 7 + 3*k) % 54
    hashData = hashData[3:]
     pwd += mapping[pwdChar][1]
 return pwd
```

How can this function result in so many collisions? The maximum sum of the first 4 nibbles can be 60 so -7 ensures it's between 0 and 53 (equal chance for all chars). +3k makes it different for every column and % 54 to make sure it fits in the mapping.